# Infobright database connection through vb script

Tags: vbscript, infobright

Can anyone tell me how to connect infobright database through vb script. I have written a code but it shows an error:

```
provider can not be found.
```

The code I have written is:

```
Option Explicit
Dim conn, sqlstr 

sqlstr = "SELECT COLLATION_NAME FROM COLLATIONS"


'Database connection info
set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
Conn.ConnectionTimeout = 30
Conn.CommandTimeout = 30
conn.open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Database=information_Schema;Username=root;Password=''")

dim  showList

Set showList = conn.execute(sqlstr)

while not showList.eof

            Wscript.echo "Collation Name:" & showList("COLLATION_NAME")

showList.MoveNext
WEND

conn.close
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBScript & Access MDB - 800A0E7A - "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508037/vbscript-access-mdb-800a0e7a-provider-cannot-be-found-it-may-not-be-prop)

Answer (score 0):

Install MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.1 and use a connection string like the following

connString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=ServerAddress;Database=DataBase;User=Username; Password=Password;"