# ADODB connection not working with Excel 32 bit

Tags: excel, vbscript, oledb, qtp, adodb

I am trying to fetch values from Excel using below code in .VBS:

```
strScenarioSheet = "D:\User.xlsx"
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
    strScenarioSheet & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"""
strSQL_TC = "Select * from [TestCases$] where [Flag]='Y'"
Set objTot = getRecords(strConnection,strSQL_TC)
MsgBox objTot.RecordCount

Function getRecords(strConnection,strSQL_TC)
    Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConn.Open strConnection
    Set objRec = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objRec.CursorLocation = 3
    objRec.Open strSQL_TC,strConnection
    objRec.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    Set getRecords=objRec.Clone
    objConn.Close
    Set objConn = Nothing
    objRec.Close
    Set objRec = Nothing
End Function
```

I get this below error:

[image]

Why do I get this provider not installed even though I have it in (C:\Windows\SysWOW64):

[image]

I tried using this **[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508037/vbscript-access-mdb-800a0e7a-provider-cannot-be-found-it-may-not-be-prop)** by clicking cscript and then running vbs. But still I get the same error.

Comment: How exactly are you invoking the script?

Comment: If you follow this guide http://support.sas.com/kb/60/322.html are you certain they are installed? are the 32 or 64 bit drivers installed?

Comment: There are many other suggestions besides the cscript one in your link - your error indicates it can't find the driver - are you certain the 32 bit version is installed?

Comment: Also an entry in the _User DSN_ tab doesn't mean anything. You need to check the _Drivers_ tab